# Unix - ls command shows some "outputted" text as a file

Tags: linux, unix, ls

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ls
total 48
4 -rw-r--r--  1 hdoostie etrade  1545 Aug  8  2012 ~
4 drwxr-xr-- 11 hdoostie etrade  4096 Dec 28  2011 det-us
4 drwxr-xr--  6 hdoostie etrade  4096 Sep 18  2012 etaf
12 -rw-r--r--  1 hdoostie etrade 11867 Jul 31  2012 l:template name="expanded_search">
4 drwxr-xr--  8 hdoostie etrade  4096 Apr 22 11:31 neo
4 drwxr-xr--  5 hdoostie etrade  4096 Jan 29 14:36 neo-apps-skins
4 drwxr-xr--  5 hdoostie etrade  4096 Feb 16  2012 neo-webapp-prospect
4 drwxr-xr--  3 hdoostie etrade  4096 Feb 22  2012 site_04_uat_in_here
4 drwxr-xr--  3 hdoostie etrade  4096 Jun 20  2012 svntest
4 drwxr-xr--  3 hdoostie etrade  4096 Feb 23  2012 xborder_in_here
```

"l:template name="expanded_search">" is some file content that somehow shows as a file.  How do I "delete" this "file"?

Comment: You mean it's a bug in `ls`? Are you sure you haven't accidentally named a file `l:template name="expanded_search">`? Why are you sure?

Comment: I have no idea what I did, but somehow file content was appearing as a file name, I tried dglo's answer and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

A way of deleting any file, no matter what characters the filename contains is using it's inode numnber. You can show that using:

```
ls -i
```

That will shou you the files with the inode number next to them. Then you can delete that file using:

```
find -ium [inode_number] -exec rm {} \;
```

But in this case it should also be enough to just quote the filename:

```
rm 'l:template name="expanded_search">'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm l:*
```

If you're the cautious type:

```
rm -i l:*
```